# Oscillate or "ping pong" between two values?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I have a path that is evaluate at time 't' and returns an orientation and position based on the path type.

The value for time is affected by the path type:

```
switch (type)
{
    case PathType.Closed:
        time = ToolBox.Wrap(time, StartTime, EndTime);
        break; // Wrap time around the path time to loop

    case PathType.Open:
        time = ToolBox.Min(time, EndTime);
        break; // Clamp the time value to the max path time range

    case PathType.Oscillating:
        break;
}
```

The missing link is oscillating.

My question is what is a good, efficient way for oscillating between two values?

For example (2, 7).  If time reaches 7 it reverses and decrements towards to 2 and once it reaches 2 it reverses and increases towards 7.

The algorithm should know whether to increase/decrease the value based on the original value so if the value is 9 it knows the answer is 7 - (Abs(7 - 9).  If the value is 14 the value has wrapped around so it will result in an increase of 1.

Higher values will also increase or decrease the value depending on the number of times it wraps around the original range.

I hope that makes sense as I'm finding it difficult to explain.

EDIT:

Doesn't oscillate with floating point values:

```
        for (float i = 0; i < 100; i += 0.1f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i, Oscillate(2.5f, 7.5f, i));
        }

    private float Oscillate(float min, float max, float value)
    {
        float range = max - min;

        float multiple = value / range;

        bool ascending = multiple % 2 == 0;
        float modulus = value % range;

        return ascending ? modulus + min : max - modulus;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand entirely what you mean, but you may want to look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970561.aspx and this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/10/23/new-wpf-features-easing-functions.aspx

Comment: I have a feeling it would involve mod (`%`) and `Math.Abs` but my head hurts. :)

Comment: This looks sort of close: http://fooplot.com/plot/6xbgckbaz5 for + ve values anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you should be abstracting this functionality into some kind of a class and not be concerned about how the implementation actually works when you're using it.  Here's an initial take on what that would look like in C++ (my C# is a little rusty).  I think you can work it into C# with only little difficulty.

```
class oscillator
{
  private:
    float min;
    float max;

    static float mod(float num, float div)
    {
        float ratio = num / div;
        return div * (ratio - std::floor(ratio));
    }

  public:
    oscillator(float a, float b)
      : min(a < b ? a : b), max(a > b ? a : b) {}

    float range() ( return max-min; }

    float cycle_length() { return 2*range(); } 

    float normalize(float val)
    {
        float state = mod(val-min, cycle_length());

        if (state > range())
            state = cycle_length()-state;

        return state + min;
    }
};
```

Comment: That increments/decrements by predefined values.  What I am after is any value input that is wrapped to the min/max range and oscillated between the two values.

Comment: Yes that is what I had in mind.  I have converted it to C# and to fit inside one static class.  Thank you. :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I came up with:

```
public static int Oscillate(int input, int min, int max)
{
    int range = max - min ;
    return min + Math.Abs(((input + range) % (range * 2)) - range);
}
```

I'm assuming `input` will be a counter starting at 0.

Comment: This works great for integers.  I have added the following line at the start of the method to bring the value into the range (i.e. relative to the min value) `value -= min;`

Comment: While this is the best variant here for integers, it's often more useful for some applications to just have (int input, int length). Also simplifies the math a bit.

Answer (score 3):

This will oscillate your numbers between 2 & 7, in this example, time is an int:

```
bool isIncreasing = time <= 7;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) //some random loop
{
    time = time + (isIncreasing ? 1 : -1);
    if (time >= 7 || time <= 2) isIncreasing = !isIncreasing;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing he wants a function that doesn't use an external variable.

Comment: The above algorithm doesn't oscillate between 2 and 7 with any given time as far as I can tell from testing.

Comment: the function would have to know which direction it moved last, would that be available? Wait, I see...

Answer (score 1):

New answer to account for float values:

```
    // Note: Increase FACTOR depending on how many decimal places of accuracy you need.
    private const float FACTOR = 10;

    public void Test()
    {
        for (float i = 0; i < 1000; i += 0.1F)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i, Oscillate(2.5F, 7.5F, i));
        }
    }

    private float Oscillate(float min, float max, float time)
    {
        return (float)(Oscillate_Aux(Upscale(min), Upscale(max), Upscale(time))) / FACTOR;
    }

    private int Upscale(float value)
    {
        return (int)(value * FACTOR);
    }

    private int Oscillate_Aux(int min, int max, int time)
    {
        int range = max - min;

        int multiple = time / range;

        bool ascending = multiple % 2 == 0;
        int modulus = time % range;

        return ascending ? modulus + min : max - modulus;
    }
```

Comment: I can't get that to work with floating point values.  See original post edit.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds a lot like periodic linear interpolation between two values.  Consider using XNA's [MathHelper.Lerp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.lerp.aspx) function as the basis for your oscillation.

Note that it uses a percentage to control the oscillation as its third parameter. You'll have to figure out how to translate your time t value into a percentile, but you could start with ex. sin(t) to see how things work.

If you're reluctant to import XNA into your project, the core equation is very simple:

```
value1 + (value2 - value1) * amount
```

**Edit**: If your question, at its heart, really is "What is a good, efficient way for oscillating between two values?", then Math.Sin(t) (or Cos) can provide you with regular oscillation between 0 and 1.

---

Answer (score 0):

this is kinds old, but it showed up in my search. Here is my simple solution for ping-pong-ing between 0 and a variable:

```
def ping_pong(value,maximum):
odd_pong = (int(value / maximum) % 2 == 1)
mod = value % maximum
if odd_pong:
    return maximum - mod
else:
```